# Y-axis opposite in iphone's view , how to adjust it like Y-axis mathematics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgpoint

I wanna shoe two point in a iphone's view

This is my code

```
UIImageView *center;
center = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"]];
[center setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
float r_rect_center_x = [r_img frame].size.width/2;
float r_rect_center_y = [r_img frame].size.height/2;
[center setCenter:CGPointMake(r_rect_center_x,r_rect_center_y)];
[r_img addSubview:center];
[center release];
```

This is center, I got result center point is (X:50,Y:60)

```
float point1_x = 60.0f;
float point1_y = 60.0f;
UIImageView *point1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"]];
[point1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
[point1 setCenter:CGPointMake(point1_x,point1_y)];
[r_img addSubview:point1];
[point1 release];
```

This is point1 , I set the center is X:60,Y:60

It should be looks like this
[image]

But it run on the simulator is like this...
[image]

**HOW TO ADJUST THE POINT1 CENTER IN Y-AXIS ???**

Many Thanks

Webber.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flip coordinates when drawing in context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145595/how-to-flip-coordinates-when-drawing-in-context)

Answer (score 0):

There's a setFlipped: method on the view. Just call it and pass `YES`.

```
[view setFlipped:YES]
```

Comment: I try this , CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 r_img.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -90 * M_PI / 180);
But only works one another point ......