# calling setNeedsDisplay in a for loop

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have some drawing code which attempts to draw layers on top of a UIView with an image displayed. The for loop code calls an update to setNeedsDisplay each time it prepares a section to be displayed but drawRect on the view only gets called at the end. Is the loop going too fast and interrupting previous calls?

```
for ( int i = 0; i < bitmapLength; i++ ) {

      if ((tfx > 0) && (tfy > 0)) {
                updateCount++;
                sourceRect = CGRectMake(sx*8, ((((ipegHeight-1)/8)-sy)*8) + osy, tfx, tfy);
                targetRect = CGRectMake(tx*8, ty*8, tfx, tfy);
                ipegSection = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(notJPEG, sourceRect);

                // create a layer and draw section onto it         
                drawLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(ctxImage, targetRect.size, nil);
                layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(drawLayer);
                CGContextDrawImage(layerContext,targetRect,ipegSection);

                // draw the layer onto the UIViews context
                CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(currentScreen, targetRect.origin, drawLayer);


                CGImageRelease(ipegSection);

                    // Update the UI
                    [targetView setNeedsDisplay];
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `drawRect` on the view only gets called at the end

More specifically, it gets called only when your method ends, and the main event loop takes over.

That is precisely the way it is supposed to work: `setNeedsDisplay` works like a "tap on the shoulder", which tells the event loop to redraw the view when it gets a chance. No matter how many times you call it, the redraw is not going to happen until your code has finished its work.

Long story short, you should make a call to `setNeedsDisplay` only once after the loop has finished.

Comment: ok that makes sense thanks. would it be possible then to draw the sections onto a single layer with an offline context and 'stamp' that onto the view when the loop finishes? not sure how to do this in code

Comment: @Md1079 You could create a bigger `drawLayer` that fits all your `targetRect`s before the loop if you prefer.

Comment: This worked! actually it kind of worked, the layer looks upside down and inverted, which might be something to do with CoreCraphics co-ordinate system will do some research

Comment: @Md1079 Great! You can invert and flip the layer using a matrix (see [this Q&A for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1145742/335858)).